# org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response has invalid status code urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder, status message is null

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to run the application provided at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml(master version) and using adfs as idp and followed all the steps given in the documentation. I am getting the below error

```
org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.impl.AssertionConsumerServiceImpl@7a033ee2 for request URL https://localhost:8443/spring-security-saml2-sample3/saml/SSO based on location attribute in metadata
- Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider
- Error validating SAML message
org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response has invalid status code urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder, status message is null
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
```

Comment: Below is the console log
- Constructing Apache XMLSignature object
- setElement("ds:Signature", "")
- setElement("ds:SignedInfo", "")
- setElement("ds:SignatureMethod", "")
- Create URI "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" class "class org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.implementations.SignatureBaseRSA$SignatureRSASHA256"
- Request for URI http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256
- Created SignatureRSA using SHA256withRSA
- setElement("KeyInfo", "")
- Adding canonicalization and signing algorithms, and HMAC output length to Signature
-

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem - last step of the guide here when setting up the Relaying Party Trust:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-idp-guide.html

"Open the provider by double-clicking it, select tab Advanced and change "Secure hash algorithm" to SHA-1"