# AuthenticationServiceException: Error validating SAML message :: AuthNResponse;FAILURE; Response has invalid status code : status message is null

Tags: spring-security, saml, adfs, spring-saml

I am trying to configure Spring SAML extension with ADFS.

I am getting the message - **status message is null**. The detailed logs are provided at the end.

I have gone through similar posts on stackoverflow. They suggest to enable RSA1 on the ADFS server.

[org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response has invalid status code urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder, status message is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365017)

[Issues while integrating ADFS with Spring SAML Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134655)

My logs seems to have RSA1 fine and settings are same on server.

**NOTE**

1. The server certificate is self-signed.
2. There is hairpinning on server and have setup hosts file entry to resolve the same.

**Edit 1:**

3. IdP initiated single-sign-on is working. But, the error happens only with SP initiated login. Also, no logs observed on ADFS server side

**LOGS**

```
DEBUG DigesterOutputStream:55 - Pre-digested input:
DEBUG DigesterOutputStream:60 - <samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" Destination="https://mysite-dev:443/empdServer/saml/SSO" ID="_4fba4628-a5d1-4fb6-85d4-f9366db2385a" InResponseTo="a4g74i6f5sdi3ebg778g3f4jab0j9c" IssueInstant="2017-05-02T14:28:51.502Z" Version="2.0"><Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://adfs.myserver/adfs/services/trust</Issuer><samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder"></samlp:StatusCode></samlp:Status></samlp:Response>
DEBUG Reference:784 - Verification successful for URI "#_4fba4628-a5d1-4fb6-85d4-f9366db2385a"
DEBUG Manifest:344 - The Reference has Type 
DEBUG SignatureValidator:70 - Signature validated with key from supplied credential
DEBUG BaseSignatureTrustEngine:148 - Signature validation using candidate credential was successful
DEBUG BaseSignatureTrustEngine:101 - Successfully verified signature using KeyInfo-derived credential
DEBUG BaseSignatureTrustEngine:102 - Attempting to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
DEBUG ExplicitKeyTrustEvaluator:91 - Successfully validated untrusted credential against trusted key
DEBUG BaseSignatureTrustEngine:104 - Successfully established trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
INFO  SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule:129 - Validation of protocol message signature succeeded, message type: {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol}Response
DEBUG SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule:131 - Authentication via protocol message signature succeeded for context issuer entity ID http://adfs.myserver.com/adfs/services/trust
DEBUG BaseMessageDecoder:85 - Successfully decoded message.
DEBUG BaseSAMLMessageDecoder:191 - Checking SAML message intended destination endpoint against receiver endpoint
DEBUG BaseSAMLMessageDecoder:210 - Intended message destination endpoint: https://mysite-dev:443/myapp/saml/SSO
DEBUG BaseSAMLMessageDecoder:211 - Actual message receiver endpoint: https://mysite-dev/myapp/saml/SSO
DEBUG BaseSAMLMessageDecoder:219 - SAML message intended destination endpoint matched recipient endpoint
DEBUG SAMLUtil:349 - Found endpoint org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.impl.AssertionConsumerServiceImpl@4189c9e9 for request URL https://mysite-dev/myapp/saml/SSO based on location attribute in metadata
DEBUG ProviderManager:162 - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG SAMLAuthenticationProvider:98 - Error validating SAML message
  org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response has invalid status code urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder, status message is null
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1519)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1475)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2017-05-02 07:28:51 INFO  SAMLDefaultLogger:127 - AuthNResponse;FAILURE;1x.1x.1x.1x;urn:myapp.mysite;http://adfs.myserver.com/adfs/services/trust;;;org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response has invalid status code urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder, status message is null
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1519)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1475)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

DEBUG SAMLProcessingFilter:350 - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error validating SAML message
DEBUG SAMLProcessingFilter:351 - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
DEBUG SAMLProcessingFilter:352 - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@20088b6d
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is on AD FS side. Your logs are merely reporting that AD FS reported an error.

You should view the AD FS event logs to see whats in the applications and services\ad fs\admin event log.

if IDP initiated signon works that means the SP side has correct details corresponding to AD FS. You just need to ensure AD FS is receiving a request based on what you configured on AD FS side.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-troubleshooting-configuring-computers(v=ws.10).aspx should help.

Comment: Thanks. This is already configured. There are no logs generated on ADFS server side on error.

Comment: That's unlikely. You should have something. Else check ad fs debug logs as per that link.